# dojo mobile textbox

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am having issues with the dojox mobile textbox in my program.  The box does not render at all when I use it.

i have tried both

```
<input dojoType="dojox.mobile.TextBox" value="test value"/>
```

and

```
<input dojoType="dojox.mobile.app.TextBox" value="test value"/>
```

Has anyone got any working examples?  I am new to dojo, so I am sure I am probably just missing something goofy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got his issue. There was a problem with requiring these widgets. After inserting this line in head `<script>` tag.

```
dojo.require("dojox.mobile.app.TextBox");
```

Issue solved. Make sure you base dojo.js has proper paths.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo itself ships with a whole bunch of tests which you could take apart and use as examples.

See here for Dojo 1.7, for example:

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0/dojo-release-1.7.0/dojox/mobile/tests/

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows dojo custom text box :

You need to specify dojo.require("dojox/mobile/TextBox");

Hope this helps.